# Consulta para contar quantos campos igual a 0 um registro possui

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Preciso retornar quantos campos igual a 0 cada registro possui e ranquear o que tiver mais zeros para baixo.
Exemplo:

```
id   | col2 | col3 | col4
1    | 1    | 0    | 0
2    | 0    | 0    | 0
3    | 0    | 1    | 4
4    | 0    | 3    | 5
5    | 3    | 2    | 40
```

O retorno neste caso deve ser:

```
id  | count(0)
5   | 0
3   | 1
4   | 1
1   | 2
2   | 3
```

Comment: Qual seu SQL???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590705/count-how-many-columns-have-a-specific-value

Comment: @PedroHenrique, agradeço o esforço, porém não posso usar consultas com sub query, pois minha tabela possui muitos campos e muitos registros. O custo na performance é alto. Além disso, não existe APPLY no MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `SUM` e ir comparando cada coluna, se a coluna for igual a `0` você coloca 1, senão coloca 0:

```
(SELECT id, SUM(IF(col2 = 0, 1, 0) + IF(col3 = 0, 1, 0) + IF(col4 = 0, 1, 0)) AS qtde FROM sua_tabela) ORDER BY qtde
```

Comment: Perfeito. Além de não ter sub query envolvida, só precisei alterar agrupando assim "group by id" e ordenar por "id" asc.